# Creating single linked list in c++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in coding and i am creating a linked list(without using class concept), but this is not working, please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void add(int n){
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = head;
    head=temp;
}
void traverse(){
    node *temp1 = head;
    while(temp1!=NULL){
        cout<<temp1->data;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
}
int main(){
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    traverse();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working"? Compile error? Runtime error? Crash?

Comment: no offense, but this code has too many mistakes. Seems like you could use a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I'm guessing that you get an "unknown identifier error" about `head`.

Comment: Don't use `malloc`, use `new`. It's never too late or too early to stop writing C in C++.

Comment: Move `node *head = NULL;` above your add function to fix the compile error.

Comment: You should not be making these kinds of very fundamental mistakes when you've reached the point in your C++ education where you're implementing linked lists. Get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), don't skip over the things you think that you already know.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
void add(int n){
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ...
```

If you are going to make a linked list in this way you need to make `head` a global variable, otherwise it gets created and destroyed each time you call `add`.

```
node *head = NULL;

void add(int n){
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ...
```

And there's really no reason not to use `new` in preference to `malloc` in a C++ program

```
    node *temp = new node;
```

Comment: There are _plenty_ of reasons not to use `new` in a C++ program. If you need dynamic allocation, use something sensible like `std::make_unique`. In 2018 `new` should be rare (though some applications do still exist).

Comment: I would upvote, if not the *"And there really is no reason not to use `new` in a C++ program*". There are plenty of reasons why **not** to use `new`. Use a smart pointer, if you are going to own something

Comment: @Fureeish I lol'd

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 18 secs lol

Comment: There is a reason not to use new in C++, actually you shouldn't use it in modern C++ which has smart pointers.

Comment: @heke slipping into third place there

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I meant as opposed to malloc, updated.

Comment: @john: Somewhat better :P `malloc` should certainly be avoided.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: Damn, should use the refresh button to make sure that "winning" is still possible :D

Comment: @john you shouldn't use global variable. You can put it as private static and have the function add and traverse friends

Answer (score 0):

1. Your program leaks all the dynamic memory that it allocates. Always free all resources that you allocate.
2. Don't ever use `malloc` in C++. Use `new` expressions instead.
3. Don't use bare owing pointers. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead (although, understanding unique pointers requires understanding of classes).

Finally, the problem is that `traverse` refers to identifier `head` which you've not declared. Sure, you have local variable `head` within the scope of `add`, but local variables only exist within the (potential) scope where they are declared. Futhermore, `add` isn't constructing a linked list, since it always uses a separate `head` for each element.

A procedural linked list implementation should take the head of the list as an argument:

```
void add(int n, node& head)

void traverse(const node& head)
```